# How does "equal protection under the law" mean same-sex couples have as much of a right to marry as heterosexual couples?

Tags: united-states, constitution, us-state-laws

First of all, I regard homosexuals as brethren & sisters. I respect their desire to marry, as I know of no way in which their lifestyle choices (of which being homosexual is not one) will affect me.

However, I fail to see how gay marriage bans are unconstitutional.

Comment: You want the long version? Read the complete official statement by the US Supreme Court on http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/14pdf/14-556_3204.pdf

Comment: Justices Roberts, Alito, Thomas, and Scalia also couldn't see how marriage bans are unconstitutional. Many think this Supreme court has been implementing policies favored by elites rather than interpreting law in a consistent way.

Comment: I can think of one way:  If same-sex marriage was illegal, then who you could or couldn't marry would be determined by your gender, which is in violation of the 14th amendment which says that the law has to apply to each gender equally.  This is not the logic that the recent supreme court decision used.

Comment: Actually, much of the reason was due process, not equal protection.

Comment: @SamIam - IANAL, but that sounds... fishy as a legal argument. You can marry anyone of opposite gender but not same, no matter what your gender is. So  the law always applied to each gender equally. Then again, a good lawyer can always prove that sky is earth and vice versa.

Comment: @DVK That's remarkably similar to arguments made about interracial sex/marriage [back in 1883](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pace_v._Alabama). If the equal protection clause *does* cover sexual orientation, it would have to cover it the same way it does race.

Comment: @cpast - Yeah, I discovered that as I tried to write up an answer.  I find the Due Process arguments quite strong, but Equal Protection to be very tacked-on.

Comment: @Geobits - I will need to read that opinion, but IMHO, equal protection is just as inapplicable to interracial marriage, on same grounds. Then again, SCOTUS is strong at doing whatever the hell it wants (witness them basically declaring everything except - for this year  so far - breathing - as "interstate commerce" and thus in scope for intrusive federal congressional laws). Lawyers always ran this country, and keep doing so :(

Comment: @DVK But without the lawyers, we'd have to use some other profession in all those jokes... Anyway, you might want to look at [Loving v. Virginia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loving_v._Virginia) if you haven't. The court there invoked both due process and equal protection, and the case is cited in the recent opinion on both points.

Comment: I can attest that *Loving v. Virginia* is cited by and relied on very heavily in this opinion.  I can't say whether it had any better rationale for Equal Protection applying, though.

Comment: @Geobits - I never joke about lawyers or bubonic plague or other dangerous things.

Comment: I'm all for harping on lawyers but, after all, we did base the country on a system of laws. We kind of set ourselves up for it to be run by lawyers.

Answer (score 4):

The Equal Protection clause of the 14th Amendment prohibits any state from denying equal protection under the law. The specific wording of the 14th Amendment is as follows:

> nor [shall any state] deny to any person within its jurisdiction the equal protection of the laws.

With regards to same-sex marriage specifically, this means that the state cannot treat heterosexual and homosexual marriages differently, as this would constitute unequal treatment under the law. From [the decision](http://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/14pdf/14-556_3204.pdf) (emphasis added):

> It is
> now clear that the challenged laws burden the liberty of
> same-sex couples, and it must be further acknowledged
> that they **abridge central precepts of equality**.  Here the
> marriage laws enforced by the respondents are in essence
> unequal: same-sex couples are denied all the benefits
> afforded to opposite-sex couples and are barred from exercising a fundamental right

The Court largely justified its decision under the Due Process clause of the 14th Amendment. However, since [Bolling v. Sharpe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolling_v._Sharpe), due process legally implies equal protection. In fact, the 5th Amendment's Due Process clause is what the Court used to rule Section 3 of the Defense of Marriage Act unconstitutional in [US v. Windsor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Windsor#Majority_opinion).

US v. Windsor provides us with more information as to specifically how bans on homosexual marriage result in unequal protection for homosexuals under the law. From the decision:

> It prevents same-sex married couples from obtaining government healthcare benefits they would otherwise receive.
>
> ...
>
> It deprives them of the Bankruptcy Code's special protections for domestic-support obligations.
>
> ...
>
> It forces them to follow a complicated procedure to file their state and federal taxes jointly.
>
> ...
>
> It prohibits them from being buried together in veterans' cemeteries.

The fact that bans on same-sex marriage result in the law treating homosexual couples and heterosexual couples differently means that such bans imply unequal protection under the law, and thus violate the Constitution's prohibition on unequal protection under the law.

Comment: I feel like this is a better argument for Equal Protection than that set out by the court.

Comment: @Bobson As happy as I am to be considered better at legal argument than the most powerful judges in the country, this is the argument set out by the Court.

Comment: "The right of same-sex couples to marry is also derived from the Fourteenth Amendment’s guarantee of equal protection ... The marriage laws at issue are in essence unequal: Same-sex couples are denied benefits afforded opposite-sex couples and are barred from exercising a fundamental right ... "The right to marry is a fundamental right inherent in the liberty of the person, and under the Due Process and Equal Protection Clauses"

Comment: I took the liberty of expanding the quote and adding emphasis.  You *did* find something I missed in my reading of it.  Thank you.

Comment: @Bobson okay, sorry if it wasn't clear that that quote was referring specifically to the Equal Protection clause. I think the answer is clear now.

Comment: So same-sex marriage bans lead to an inability to obtain the same benefits enjoyed by opposite-sex married couples. Okay, but it seems to me that the Court should have allowed same-sex couples to engage in civil unions that - for legal purposes - would entitle said couples to the same benefits as married couples.

Comment: @moonman239 what is the argument to come up with a new legal term to replace an existing legal term that already encompasses the legal definition?

Comment: @moonman239 Brown v. Board. It has to be the same institution. A separate but equal one wouldn't really be equal.

Comment: @moonman239 - To further Avi's point, the only other possibility would have been to declare that the government has *no* say in marriage whatsoever, and that the civil side of the marriage process needs to be replaced with something that isn't marriage - in other words, rather than marriage for all, civil unions for all. Then marriage would be a purely religious term with no legal standing.

Comment: @Bobson The Supreme Court had no Constitutional grounds upon which they could insist that governments start calling legal marriages "civil unions". But you are correct in that they couldn't call gay marriages one thing and straight ones another. They'd have to be the same thing.

Comment: @Avi - That particular term, not necessarily, but they might have been able to force the concept via separation of church and state.  Something like "marriage is traditionally a religious ceremony, which means the government should not be involved in approving it at all.  However, there's a logical need for a similar state to be formalized for all secular purposes.  Thus..." I'm by no means a lawyer, and I'm not saying that it *would* be possible to construct a constitutionally sound argument in that direction.  Just that doing so would also avoid the problems inherent in "separate but equal".

Comment: @Bobson having all legal marriages be civil unions would get around the "separate but equal" problem. It's just that the court can't mandate it. For example, marriage has never traditionally been an exclusively religious institution, and so the Court would be wrong to decide that the government administering marriages is an establishment clause violation.

Comment: Quoting something that *people* have to be treated equally, and then concluding that a law that treats *couples* differently is unconstitutional, is a blatant non sequitur.